# cannot import name 'load_model' from 'keras.engine.saving'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-import, openai-gym

## Issue :

I am trying to use [the gym connect4 env](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).
When running this sample code :

```
import gym
from gym_connect_four import RandomPlayer, ConnectFourEnv
env: ConnectFourEnv = gym.make("ConnectFour-v0")

player1 = RandomPlayer(env, 'Dexter-Bot')
player2 = RandomPlayer(env, 'Deedee-Bot')
result = env.run(player1, player2, render=True)
reward = result.value
print(reward)
```

I am having this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14304\94530224.py in <module>
      1 import gym
----> 2 from gym_connect_four import RandomPlayer, ConnectFourEnv
      3 env: ConnectFourEnv = gym.make("ConnectFour-v0")
      4 
      5 player1 = RandomPlayer(env, 'Dexter-Bot')

c:\Users\Axel\Documents\_ReinforcementJourney\Connect4\gym-connect-four\gym_connect_four\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from gym.envs.registration import register
----> 2 from .envs.connect_four_env import ConnectFourEnv, Player, RandomPlayer, SavedPlayer, ResultType
      3 
      4 register(
      5     id='ConnectFour-v0',

c:\Users\Axel\Documents\_ReinforcementJourney\Connect4\gym-connect-four\gym_connect_four\envs\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from gym_connect_four.envs.connect_four_env import ConnectFourEnv, Player, RandomPlayer, SavedPlayer, ResultType

c:\Users\Axel\Documents\_ReinforcementJourney\Connect4\gym-connect-four\gym_connect_four\envs\connect_four_env.py in <module>
     11 from gym import error
     12 from gym import spaces
---> 13 from keras.engine.saving import load_model
     14 
     15 from gym_connect_four.envs.render import render_board

ImportError: cannot import name 'load_model' from 'keras.engine.saving'
```

## What I tried :

I tried to update every packages i had using

```
conda update --all
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow

I tried to change `connect_four_env.py`'s way to import keras by changing `from keras.engine.saving import load_model` to `from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.saving import load_model`

None of these attempts solved my issue, I hope there is something to do.

Answer (score 0):

From TF v2.3 everything under tensorflow.python.keras.engine.saving was moved to tensorflow.python.keras.saving
Please replace the below import statement

```
from keras.engine.saving import load_model
```

whith the following

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```